# Strange Workflow warning in Sharepoint farm

Tags: 2007, workflow, error

I keep getting a large number of the following warnings in my SharePoint Farm.

```
Event Type: Warning
Event Source: Office SharePoint Server
Event Category: Workflow Features 
Event ID: 7397
Date:  1/31/2010
Time:  1:22:21 PM
User:  N/A
Computer: MOB-INTRA-APP2
Description:
message
For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

I am using Windows 2003 R2/ MOSS 2007 + SP1 / SQL 2005.

This warning is being repeated too many times in the event log.

Any idea what this warning might be about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a thread over on the [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointworkflow/thread/5be7fd84-8889-4be7-b785-608fc9ea0191) forums about this, unfortunately with no resolution at the time of writing.

My suspicion is that this isn't reflective of anything which is a real problem. Wish I could say for sure.